# Deny deletion of file but then programs cant save new files. (With a twist)

Tags: permissions

This has been covered a million times, but after trying every suggestion on here, I am still stuck.

I have a Windows 10 system. We need to lock down a folder to allow files to be created (both manually and via programs)

I can get it to the point of not being allowed to delete the files, however then programs cant save.

I have

Allow:
Traverse Folder, List Folder, Read Attributes, Read extended attributes, Create files, Write Attributes, Write extended attributes, Read Permissions

With these rights, I can delete but not save
The ONLY way I can write the new file is to allow delete.

This makes absolutly no sense. Please someone explain what on earth is going on.